# Using Google Earth Enterprise & ArcGIS platform together?

Tags: shapefile, kml, arcgis-platform, google-earth-enterprise

I have been fielded a few questions about Google Earth Enterprise (GEE) -which I don't know anything about, I'm having a time finding answers to the two following questions, which can probably be summed up by:

- Do you use both GEE & ArcGIS? And, if so, how do you interact between the two?"
- Can you consume GEE with ArcGIS? I am pretty sure you can bring ArcGIS created shapefiles into GEE, but does it work the other way around without converting KML data to shapefiles?
- Can you use GEE as an image service? My instincts say the answer to this question is "yes", but I am unable to find an actual answer.

Comment: You can view KML in ArcGlobe - http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_to_access_the_KML_tools/00q800000060000000/

Comment: MaryBeth it is available in ArcGIS 9.3 http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Displaying_KML_data_in_ArcGlobe

Comment: If you are using Google Earth Enterprise, and the support payments are up to date, then you have access to the enterprise support team at Google. You also have access to the google earth enterprise user group. These are good resources for any work with the enterprise version. If you need more info, you can email me at mevanoff@google.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Arc2Earth Desktop](http://www.arc2earth.com/products/desktop/) is the only tool I know of that provides a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

•   Develop an ecosystem monitoring methodology approved/agreed by key stakeholders covering biodiversity, pest potential/damage, soil sampling, erosion evidence, vegetation cover regeneration that fits with existing GIS systems or make recommendation for the upgrading/improving them.

Comment: Welcome to our site!  I think MaryBeth is looking for the answers on the mechnics of using them together, rather than applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can't consume GEE services with ArcGIS.  You can build GEE resources from shapefiles and then symbolize in google fusion.  GEE does not provide conversions to/from kml files.  Use Esri tools for that.  Assuming you are using an Esri reference when you ask about an "image service", the answer is no.