# Add Google Basemap to ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, google-earth

I am looking for a way to add Google Earth imagery to ArcMap 10.  Over a year ago, a GIS.SE member mentioned [Arc2Earth](http://www.arc2earth.com/) was the only way to accomplish this ([04/2011 thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8465/google-earth-enterprise-arcgis-how-do-you-use-them-together)).  Another somewhat convoluted approach is described [here](http://gis.yohman.com/up206a/how-tos/how-to-add-a-google-earth-satellite-image-into-arcmap/).  Has there been any progress in bringing Google Earth imagery to ArcGIS?

Comment: what country / area is your project in?

Comment: curious why the current Arc2Earth solution is not an option? It now supports layout view and projections, and the monthly subscription price ($49/m US) is reasonable for small or large projects. more info: http://www.arc2earth.com/services/data-services/

Comment: OpenStreetMap live tiles can be loaded via the LPK references - http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=79fbdd5b4fbc47da842948b255276893

Comment: @Mapperz - I think OP may be looking for the google satellite view.

Comment: go here for information you need [http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/40707-Using-Google-Maps-with-ArcMap-10](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/40707-Using-Google-Maps-with-ArcMap-10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree Google's imagery is better than Bing's in many cases. I also think the answer is correct, that you can't use Google's imagery inside ArcGIS and probably won't be able to - ever. If you're in Minnesota, we've taken a stab at this problem by setting up a "Composite Imagery Service": http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/wms/composite_image.html

It is very "Google-like" in that it provides a single layer image service that automatically switches to an appropriate set of air photos or satellite imagery depending on the scale and extent. We update the "low altitude" imagery as much as we can to keep it fresh. The images are provided as a WMS. I know this isn't an answer nationwide, but I thought it would be useful to post this here in case any Minnesota users ask this question. I also encourage other states to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in the states, you may prefer http://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/ as I think neither Google nor ESRI allows to get google maps in your desktop application.

Google in the first place doesn't provide services such as WMS. Please check following links:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/40707-Using-Google-Maps-with-ArcMap-10
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/google-maps-api/FORJbnvxICw/hwQeyjvr-CsJ

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps basemap integration within ArcGIS is currently 'under consideration' at Arcideas, see [here](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008Gln&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=ArcGIS%252BDesktop&sort=popular&status=Under%2bConsideration)

Not a solution as such but it's certainly a feature that is on the radar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about whether it's allowed to include Google's Slippy Tiles into ArcGIS, but if you only want to download some particular area, join all tiles into single geo-referenced image, then load it into ArcMap, you may try SAS Planet

https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.planet.bin/downloads/

Most tile servers provided there are in Russian, so you may need to change a bit on map settings into English or your country code.
[image: SAS Planet]
You only need to

1. click selection manager to make start create selection
2. click on map
3. click other end of your selection
4. pop up dialog will ask you to download all tiles
5. if all downloaded, you need to join all tiles into single file, to stitch it..
6. browse where you want to save it onto your harddrive
7. make sure correct zoom
8. change projection
9. and make sure you create WLD and Auxiliary XML File, so your file will be georeferenced correctly automagically.

It's absolutely faster then manually geo-reference / rectify image from Google Earth.

Answer (score 0):

Arc2Earth is dead, Hdgooglebasemaps has replaced it. http://www.hdgooglebasemaps.com/  It has maps, satellite, and a transparent hybrid layer which is my favorite.  The satellite imagery is lightyears better, and I vastly prefer the Google maps over the bing and OSM options.  Even OSM has gotten a lot more restrictive lately.

Comment: Before using HDGoogleBasemaps perhaps check whether it is legal: https://community.esri.com/ideas/2713?commentID=70216#comment-70216

Answer (score -3):

I have been able to find the below solution (last post12-06-2013 12:11 AM reply from the user: anh_like_em2002

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/40707-Using-Google-Maps-with-ArcMap-10

*"Default Re: Using Google Maps with ArcMap 10
    the tool can down here http://www.mediafire.com/download/d0...oogleSetup.zip, pls: gis2cad@gmail.com for help"*

Hope that helps...